# Why is Git committing everything that I have on my computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Using Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails instructions, I typed the following into the command line:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git status
```

The output I got doesn't make sense.  It looks like everything on my computer is being committed, i.e. my web browsing history.

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage) 
#
#   modified:   .DS_Store
#   new file:   .Trash/.DS_Store
#   modified:   .bash_history
#   modified:   .gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/latest_specs.4.8
#   new file:   .gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/quick/Marshal.4.8/treetop-1.4.12.gemspec
#   new file:   .gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.34.gemspec 
#   modified:   .gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/specs.4.8
#   modified:   Desktop/.DS_Store
#   modified:   Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Metadata/.info
#   modified:   Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/7A5B88B6-2E8C-44D5-B3C5-96C523D66818/Metadata/.info
#   modified:   Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/Intervals_31838DA3-3634-5B48-BAA4-074D9844D0AB.plist
#   modified:   Library/Application Support/Dock/FD847662-EDEA-43DC-8969-18D1DD48507E.db
#   modified:   Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings/Auto Save Session.sublime_session
#   modified:   Library/Application Support/Ubiquity/peer-0773FD5E-421F-A363-E209-F9D5E42A0F5F-v23/item-info.db
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/Bookmarks/2AD8D7AF-5B59-4BF5-9C80-749756908961.webbookmark
#   modified:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/.tracked filenames.plist
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-282.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-283.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-284.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-285.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-286.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-287.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-288.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-289.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-290.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-291.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-292.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-293.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-294.webhistory
#   new file:   Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/Safari history item-295.webhistory
```

Before trying to commit, I had ran `$ rails server` in a different terminal and got the output below:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-10-31 12:30:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-10-31 12:30:26] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-10-12) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
[2012-10-31 12:30:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3773 port=3000


Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-31 12:52:53 -0400
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Served asset /rails.png - 200 OK (3ms)
```

From a previous question, I know `$ rails server` will continue to run until I close the terminal window.  Please help!  Why is everything from my computer, including web history being committed to Git?

Comment: rails server will continue to run until you shutdown it with `Ctrl-C`... as it states on the fourth line of log.

Comment: this should not be tagged ruby-on-rails

Comment: There is in fact an implied subquestion on how to stop the rails server... but I removed the ror3 and github tags.

Comment: If I wanted to commit to git, am I allowed to stop the rails server?  I was under the impression that it had to keep running.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you ran the command in your homefolder. You need to use `cd /path/to/your/code` to ensure that you are in the code folder. Use `pwd` to see the directory you are currently in.

Comment: It's worth a note that each terminal you open will be in your home directory by default, not the directory of the other terminal. You said you ran the rails server in one terminal (it ran fine), but you opened a new terminal to do the git commit. That's perfectly fine, just remember that the terminal can't guess which directory you want to be in. You have to tell it.

Comment: I typed the following into the command line: `$ cd /Users/XXXXXX/rails_projects/first_app` to tell the terminal which directory I wanted.  I then went about the steps to commit to git.  When I typed in `$ git status`, I got `# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`.  Why is the branch master saying that there is nothing to commit?   I also did `git reset --hard`.  Did I make my problem worse?  Thank you!

Comment: @LearningHowToCode you need to do `git init` then do `git add .` from within that folder. Then you can run `git status`

Comment: @Mitch, I did `git init` --> `git add` --> `git status` and got output saying that there was nothing to commit on the branch master.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: @LearningHowToCode you need to do `git add .` (with a period)